# Shorten excel formula by user defined function VBA

Tags: vba, function, matrix, range, excel-udf

My ultimate goal is to shorten this formula using a user definded function in VBA, with the following as my parameter A1:C10, A1:A10, E1, B1:B10, F1 (this will vary, this is just an pure example)

Excel formula:

```
=index(A1:C10,match(1,(A1:A10=E1)*(B1:B10=F1),0),G1)
```

Using user defined function, it gonna be something like this:

```
=pick(A1:C10, A1:A10, E1, B1:B10, F1, G1)
```

My VBA code is like this, however, it does not work. Please expert, help me. Many thanks.

```
Function pick(range As range, con1 As range, con1a As range, con2 As range, con2a As range, col As range) As Variant

pick = WorksheetFunction.Index(range, Match(1, (con1 = con1a) * (con2 = con2a), 0), col)

End Function
```

Comment: VBA can't do matrix operations such as `con = con1a`.  You will need to do that in a loop.

Comment: Hi, would you mind sharing the code of how you would do this kind of stuff ? Sorry, I am a noob and hope that I can learn from this little exercisee. Thanks

Comment: showing an example with expected output would also help.

Answer (score 0):

use the Evaluate method:

```
Function pick(range As range, con1 As range, con1a As range, con2 As range, con2a As range, col As range) As Variant

pick = Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate("Index(" & range.Address(1,1,,1) & ",Match(1, (" & con1.Address(1,1,,1) & " = " & con1a.Address(1,1,,1) & ") * (" & con2.Address(1,1,,1) & " = " & con2a.Address(1,1,,1) & "), 0), " & col.Address(1,1,,1) & ")")

End Function
```